# Update HAML class with Angular

Tags: angularjs, haml

I'm trying to update the class of an element via an angular binding. I can successfully achieve this with html:

```
<input type='text' ng-model='data.message'></input><br>
<div class='{{ data.message }}'></div>
```

However, I am trying to do the same with HAML and I'm failing:

```
%input{ type: 'text', ng_model: 'data.message' }
%div{ class: {{ data.message }} }
```

gives me:

```
application.haml:15: unterminated regexp meets end of file
application.haml:15: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting '}'):
```

How should I convert the HTML above into HAML? Is it even possible to use HAML with Angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `{{data.message}}` into quotes

```
%input{ type: 'text', ng_model: 'data.message' }
%div{ class: '{{data.message}}' }
```

[Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VYKgmm)

Comment: Thanks man... why does the key need to be a string in `'ng-app'=> 'App'` but a symbol in `ng_model: data.message`?

Comment: @Starkers I don't fully get HAML syntax, but this `=>` (arrow' sign) is used when you have two strings. The code can be changed to  `"ng-model" => "data.message"` and it also works.